# Probability of ending at same chair after 6 die rolls

Tags: probability, combinatorics, dice

I came across this question from a trading interview. There are 4 chairs in a circle. You roll  a die.  If it comes up 4, you move one chair counterclockwise. If it is any other face, you move clockwise that number of chairs. For example, if I got a 6 I would move 6 chairs clockwise, which is equivalent to 6 mod 4 = 2 chairs clockwise. The question is what is the probability of  ending up in the same chair you started in after 6 rolls?

I tried tackling this with the law of total probability, conditioning outcomes on X, the number of 4's we get, so then the other 6-X rolls have to sum to a number that satisfies some modulo operation, but I found that approach to devolve into a tedious counting exercise. Is there any more intuitive, straightforward approach that relies on some key insight I am missing?

Comment: Is this meant to be done mentally?  Easy enough to compute the transition matrix and raise it to the sixth power, though maybe not so easy mentally.  Of course, it's sensible to guess $\frac 14$ which turns out to be very close.

Comment: Hint: the odds on a roll of rotating $1,2,3$ times clockwise is are all equal. If $p_n$ is the probability of ending on the same seat after $n$ rounds, then $p_{n+1}=\frac{1}3(1-p_n).$

Comment: Thanks for the hint, @ThomasAndrews! That simplified things a lot.